# Error: `_Token` was not found in request data on CakePHP 4 ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I created a form with php with js on change in the radio buttons:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['id' => 'filter']); ?>

    <?php foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) { ?>
      <label class="alignRadio">

        <?php echo $this->Form->radio('categoria', [$value->titulo => ''], ['hiddenField' => false, 'class' => 'formRadio switch-inputs', 'label' => false]) ?>
        <span class="radio">
          <?php echo $this->Html->image('/content/categories/' . $value->icone, ['class' => 'icon']);?>
          <?php echo $value->titulo; ?>
        </span>
      </label>
    <?php } ?>

  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

on my default.php, I'm calling the csrfToken:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(sprintf(
            'var csrfToken = %s;',
            json_encode($this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken'))
        )); ?>
```

and then the ajax with js

```
$(function() {

    $(".switch-inputs").on('change', function() {
        var categoria = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'blog/filtrar',
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken, 
            },
            data: {
                'categoria': categoria,
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#posts div').fadeOut(400).remove(400);

            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#posts').fadeOut(0).html(data).fadeIn(200);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm also unlocking the action on the blog controller:

```
        $this->FormProtection->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['carregar', 'filtrar']);
```

and loading the FormProtection on the AppController:

```
$this->loadComponent('FormProtection');
```

But i'm still getting this error, here's the error log:

```
2022-07-12 18:24:07 error: [Cake\Http\Exception\BadRequestException] `_Token` was not found in request data. in /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php on line 143
Stack Trace:
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php:97
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:309
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:286
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php:92
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:640
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:130
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:115
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:317
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- /******/vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php:124
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:174
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:162
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:161
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:126
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- /******/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- /******/webroot/index.php:40

Request URL: /blog/carregar
```

I need the ajax to retrieve me the view, but it's not finding the token. I took a look on the html renderized code and the token is there.

Token

[image]

Comment: I would think you'd need to put quotes around the token value in your JS: `'var csrfToken = "%s";'`. Any why `json_encode` it? It's just a string?

Comment: Have you looked into your Network dev tools to verify that `_Token` is in the Request payload?